# Tortoise Diff not showing up

Tags: tortoisesvn

I checked out some source code, then did an update to set my working copy.

I noticed that even though I added the diff options in my settings for my context menu in Windows Explorer, the diff options don't show up.

Am I missing something here?  I think that my local copy is not versioned until check-in.  But is there a way to perform a diff on some code that just changed locally?

Lets say you regen some code in your DL.  And it updates a bunch of classes.  How can you do a diff from the previous save without having to check in the code to SVN then do a repo diff?

Answer (score 5):

First, your working copy **is** versioned from the very moment you perform a checkout. If it isn't versioned it isn't a working copy.

Second, there's nothing to *diff* unless you have uncommitted changes. Have you changed code in your working copy? An *update* does not count as local modification.

**Update:** Please note that you cannot diff a folder: you can only diff a *file*. For folders, I suggest the "Check for modifications" dialogue.

Comment: the code changed in my working copy, thus I see the red overlay.  But when I right-click no diff options appear even though I have the diff options checked to show up in my context menu in Tortoise settings.

Comment: Can't diff a folder. That's just peachy.

Comment: Peachy? I'd say it's lame. Landed here with the same confusion.  @ChrisB saved me.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question , but there is no accepted answer.

If you right click on the folder that has the updated files and choose `commit` (don't panic :-D). You then see a list of all your changed files about to be committed.

You can simply double click the file you are interested in and you'll get a diff of your changes. When you are done, just click `cancel` and nothing will be committed.

Comment: BTW - It could simply be not showing the diff option because you are clicking on the folder. If you click on an individual file you should get the diff option as Álvaro mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I've had the exact same issue, but it might help anyway...
I faced a situation where differences window was not showing when requesting "SVN Check for Modification". That was actually a problem due to the window itself, not really SVN.
Solution:
Open Tortoise SVN settings window (Right-Click -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings). Select "Saved Data" tab. Click "Clear" button for "Dialog sizes and positions".

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for that solution!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your TSVN Cache might not be updating correctly. The context menu should know what files have local modifications and offer you the Diff option. If you right click and do "Check for Modifications" does it show a local change?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do a diff between two "saves" of your working copy without having committed the first "save", you are doing something wrong: the whole point of using a system like Subversion is to let you explicitly mark "saves worth diffing against" by committing them, so you should have committed that "save".

If you're not doing this because it's undoable to order all the small "save"s you want to do this into a tidy sequence of Subversion commits, you may want to try a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control).

Answer (score 0):

If you have WinMerge open, the Diff doesn't show up. Close it then the diff will be displayed.
I had it open comparing two folders, I was able to find the difference using Check for modification. after I closed the WinMerge the Diff option show up.